# Redis connection [cache] not configured error with laravel

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-5, redis

I am trying to use redis for caching in laravel.

I have install redis locally and I know it is working as I am able to run horizon queues and workers.

I also get a response when doing

redis-cli PING

but when I try this code

```
$user = Cache::get('User:' .$Id , function ($Id) {
    return User::where('id', '=', $Id)->firstOrFail();
});
```

I get the error

```
 Redis connection [cache] not configured.
```

I have changed my .env to have the following entry

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
```

Answer (score 6):

Find this in `cache.php`

```
    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'cache',
    ],
```

and change it to:

```
    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

can u set redis configration in `config/database.php` like this

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', 'footbar'), //if password otherwise set null 
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],
```

> other wise set in .env file

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

**then run artisan command**

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

**step 1 : Configuration : config/database.php add below array**

```
'redis' => array(
'cluster' => false,
'default' => array(
'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
'database' => env(‘REDIS_DATABASE',0),
),
),
```

**Step 2 : Configuration : .env file**

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_DATABASE=0
```

**Step 3 : Config/cache.php**

```
'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to other answer and in case that you use the redis as queue driver, verify that redis connection is set to "default" in the `queue.php`configuration file.